# Pythonic way to apply format to all strings in dictionary without f-strings

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, formatting

I have a dictionary that looks like this:

```
d = {
  'hello': 'world{x}',
  'foo': 'bar{x}'
}
```

What's the pythonic way of running `format` on all values in the dictionary? For example with `x = 'TEST'` the end result should be:

```
{
  'hello': 'worldTEST',
  'foo': 'barTEST'
}
```

NB: I'm loading `d` from another module so can not use f-strings.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're using Python-3.6+ the pythonic way is using f-strings, otherwise a dictionary comprehension:

```
In [147]: x = 'TEST'

In [148]: d = {
     ...:   'hello': f'world{x}',
     ...:   'foo': f'bar{x}'
     ...: }

In [149]: d
Out[149]: {'foo': 'barTEST', 'hello': 'worldTEST'}
```

In python < 3.6:

```
d = {
     'hello': f'world{var}',
     'foo': f'bar{var}'
    }

{k: val.format(var=x) for k, val in d.items()}
```

Comment: I should have specified,  but the dictionary `d` is in another module, making the f-strings approach not possible. I've updated my question and the title to reflect this.

Comment: In the more general case (where one wants to use any of the variables in scope), `val.format(**globals())` could be appropriate.

Comment: @PatrickHaugh: Presumably `locals()` if you want to use locals. You can also use `format_map` instead of `format` to avoid the need for `**` unpacking.

Answer (score 1):

In python 3.6 use f strings, and then run a for loop to apply the changes to each value in the dict using the format method.

```
x = 'TEST'
d = {
     'hello': f'world{x}',
      'foo': f'bar{x}'

    }

for value in d.values():
     value.format(x)
     print(value)
```

this gets you the output you're looking for:

```
 worldTEST
 barTEST
```